# Which RGB-D sensor is better with ROS packages?

Tags: ros, xtion, libopenni, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While looking for specifications of Kinect and Xtion sensors, I found various versions such as Kinect Version 2, Kinect for Xbox one, Kinect for Xbox 360, Xtion Pro Live and WAVI Xtion. I wanted to know which one of these sensors is better to use especially when using them with ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238961/which-rgb-d-sensor-is-better-with-ros-packages?/) by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've only used the Xtion Pro Live and it works pretty well. I've seen a lot of people using Kinect v2 cameras, so there will be a lot of support for these. They are also higher resolution than the Xtion Pro live and the v1 so will be a bit better. I personally wouldn't buy one of the original Kinects, but it's up to you as they are pretty cheap.
If I was to buy one today I would buy a Kinect v2, because they have good resolution and a good community of support.

---

Originally posted by [fleishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/27385/fleishman/) with karma: 56 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-07-07**:
Also note that the original kinects needed a separate power supply; the Xtions draw enough power from USB.